# Unhandled dwarf expression

Tags: opcode

Can anybody tell me what exactly the following segmentation fault means?

```
Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0x93
```

Its on solaris 10 i386.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I updated gdb to 7.2 and gcc to 4.4.7, but still i have "Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0xf3"

Comment: Python optimized pyc bytecode running on a version with different compiler flags?

Answer (score 15):

This sort of error message ("unhandled dwarf expression") can occur if your version of GDB is too old (older than the compiler that generated the code). Try installing the latest version of gdb and running that.

Comment: as a data point, gdb 6.5 didn't work, gdb 7.2 did, with gcc 4.4.7

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same error message with gdb-7.8.1 and gcc-4.4.5

Answer (score 2):

This may not immediately help, but "dwarf" probably refers to the [DWARF Debugging Standard](http://dwarfstd.org/).

The [wikipedia entry for DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) indicates that the file format contains "byte-coded instructions for simple, special-purpose finite state machines". This may mean that you have a corrupted debug info file of some kind, but without more information I wouldn't be able to guess further.

Comment: hi, added some backtrace info - does it make any sense?