# Printing allocatable array in Fortran with gdb: Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0x97

Tags: gdb, fortran, fortran2003

I've debugged the following piece of code in Cygwin and Eclipse using gdb as the debugger:

```
program codetest
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    integer, parameter :: N = 10
    real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: vector
    integer :: i

    allocate(vector(1:N))

    forall(i = 1:10)
        vector(i) = sqrt(real(i, dp))
    end forall

    write(*, '(F7.3, 1X)', advance = 'no') (vector(i), i = 1, N)

    deallocate(vector)
end program codetest
```

When running gdb, I attempt to print the allocatable array "vector" following its allocation, but I end up with the following:

```
(gdb) p vector
Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0x97
```

I've scoured Stack Overflow and Google, but I haven't found anything that gets to the heart of the matter. I've checked out the following,

- http://numericalnoob.blogspot.be/2012/08/fortran-allocatable-arrays-and-pointers.html
- [Unhandled dwarf expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608361/unhandled-dwarf-expression)
- [Fortran print allocatable array in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211692/fortran-print-allocatable-array-in-gdb)

but I'm still not understanding what the problem is or how to fix it. I've gotten the same complaint from gdb in Eclipse (Mars.1 Release, 4.5.1) when trying to print/display the contents of a derived type. Current specs about my machine/compiler/debugger include the following:

- Windows 8.1
- gfortran version: GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.9.3
- gdb version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is just a duplicate! The answer you linked clearly states you nead another branch of gdb which incorporates the pach from the Archer branch. Your gdb version just doesn't have the capability. What do you want to know more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447741/can-gdb-be-used-to-print-values-of-allocatable-arrays-of-a-derived-type-in-fortr?rq=1   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656030/gdb-printing-two-dimensional-fortran-array?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I updated my version of gdb, everything's gravy now.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, I just needed to update my version of gdb, which I did via Cygwin. I'm now running gdb version 7.9.1-1 with the same version of gfortran as before.